# USB-C to Lightning cable: Connecting iPhone to USB-C peripherals

Tags: iphone, usb, lightning

The iPhone 11 Pro/Pro Max come with USB-C to Lightning cables for fast charging, and the regular iPhone 11 supports them.

Regular Lightning supports HDMI output via an Apple dongle.

Does the USB-C to Lightning cable support HDMI output too? If I were to plug the phone and cable into a USB-C hub, would the hub’s HDMI output work?

If I were to plug the phone via Lightning to USB-C cable directly into a USB-C monitor, would that work?

Answer (score 4):

No, plugging your Lightning to USB-C cable into a display with USB-C inputs would not allow the iPhone to send video to the display.  The Lightning to HDMI adapter actually has a small computer (as in small enough to fit in a single chip) inside to do the HDMI conversion.  Here's someone that tore one of those adapters apart:  https://boingboing.net/2019/07/29/teardown-of-apples-lightning.html

If you were to connect your iPhone to most USB-C docks then it's not likely to do much but maybe charge your phone.  Most USB-C docks rely on the connected host to provide a DisplayPort signal, and the dock has a chip in it (perhaps much like that Lightning dock) to provide the HDMI conversion.  Maybe a dock like you describe exists, I just have my doubts.

The Lightning to USB-C cable I have, which is not from Apple, can only charge my iPhone and provide USB 2.0 data to and from my MacBook.  I tried plugging in different USB-C devices and it doesn't appear to support attaching anything else.

This brings my own question to this answer and I wonder if
an Apple Lightning to USB-C cable be able to do more. It’s advertised as a charging cable and not a high speed data cable so I wonder about USB 3.0 speeds to my MacBook Pro for things like being an internet hot spot, or move files back and forth.

I presume at some speed it would  allow me to connect USB-C drive and transfer files.

I'm rather disappointed with the Lightning to USB-C cable I have.  I was expecting far more than just a USB 2.0 cable.  I was not expecting HDMI out of such a cable, just something more than 12 watts charging and faster USB data than 480 Mbps.

Comment: The apple cables are not high speed data but so good work charging. There are quite a few cables though -  not every one is the same.

Answer (score -2):

I think you can use the USB-C to USB Adapter which lets you connect iOS devices and many of your standard USB accessories to a USB-C or Thunderbolt 3 (USB-C) enabled Mac and other devices.